# Use require() on client-side JS webpage ('promisify is not a function' error with browserify)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, browserify

I'm trying to create a simple webpage that uses Puppeteer (a NodeJS library for web scraping).
I can't run my page because my main.js file that I link to from my index.html uses Puppeteer through require() and gives me an error when the page is loaded since require() can't be used on client-side.

I tried to solve this by using Browserify to bundle my main.js file with the Puppeteer dependency but I get the following error in the browser console when running the page with the newly created bundle.js from Browserify:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: promisify is not a function
> at Object.37.debug (bundle.js:2470)
> at o (bundle.js:1)
> at bundle.js:1
> at Object.109.../common/Debug.js (bundle.js:14756)
> at o (bundle.js:1)
> at bundle.js:1
> at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:15470)
> at Object.111.../common/Browser.js (bundle.js:16004)
> at o (bundle.js:1)
> at bundle.js:1
> ```

I tried installing promisify and util.promisify but it didn't solve the issue.

The files are super basic to test if it works and look like this:

**index.html**

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
> <meta charset="UTF-8">
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
> <title>Document</title> </head> <body>
> <h1>My Page</h1>
> <script src="bundle.js"></script> </body> </html>
> ```

**main.js**

> ```
> const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 
> alert('Hello');
> ```

**command for browserify**

> browserify main.js -o bundle.js

Any ideas why it doens't work?

Answer (score 2):

Browserify solves the problem of `require` not being supported by browsers.

It also allows you to use tools like npm and yarn to manage JS packages since it can resolve them using `require` like Node.js can.

It doesn’t solve the problem of modules, like `puppeteer`, depending on APIs that are provided by Node.js and not by browsers. You can’t run Puppeteer client-side.

Comment: I see. Didn't think about it but it makes sense. Then I'll have to separate it. Thanks!